# how to compare two strings from a paragraph in php

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find a solution for a problem i'm facing. ihave the following paragraph

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **!qwerty** consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sapien velit, aliquet eget commodo nec, auctor a sapien. **!qwerty** Nam eu neque vulputate diam rhoncus *!**bart*** faucibus. Curabitur quis varius libero. Lorem.

Where i have to eliminate repeated values preceding by a !. For ex: there are two !qwerty strings in the paragraph and i want to notify the user who inserts the paragraph to restrict the repeated value to one without affecting the third !bart tag, how do i do it in php. so far i tried strcmp, preg_match and str_pos which all din't work and it is giving me a headache.

The code what i tried so far(i'm sorry if it is has unnecessary code because i'm still learning):

```
$data="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, !qwerty consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sapien velit, aliquet eget commodo nec, auctor a sapien. !qwerty Nam eu neque vulputate diam rhoncus !bart faucibus. Curabitur quis varius libero. Lorem.";
$dat=  explode(" ", $data);//names are exploded in to array 

foreach($dat as $d) {

    $compare1=in_array($d,$dat);

    if(strpos($d ,'!') !== FALSE ){

        $i=0;
        $d2=count($dat);
        while ($i<$d2) {

            $d_w=$dat[$i];
            //print_r($d_w);
            $regex="/!+([a-zA-z0-9._-]+)/";
            $d1= preg_match($regex, $d);
            $i++;
            $d21=$d;
            $d3= count($d2);
            $d4= parse_str($d2,$out);

            $d5===strcmp($d, $d_w);
            $d6=== strpos($d_w, $d);

            var_dump("<p>".$d5."</p><i>".$d6); 
            if ($d21===$d_w ) {
                $tag=1; 
                $d7=$tag+tag;
                print_r("<span>".$tag."</span>");echo '<br>';print_r("<p>".$d7);
                if($d7>1){
                    echo 'only one tag is allowed per post';  
                }
            }
        }
        //var_dump($compare1);
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Use `preg_match_all` to find all occurrences of ! followed by a group of letters (plus other characters if applicable, up to you to define that), and then check the resulting array of matches for duplicates, using `array_count_values` (if any of the entries has a count > 1, alert the user.)

Comment: If you have trouble coming up with the proper regular expression to match those parts, start with a regex tutorial and https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
$data1="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, !qwerty consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sapien velit, aliquet eget commodo nec, auctor a sapien. !qwerty Nam eu neque vulputate diam rhoncus !bart faucibus. Curabitur quis varius libero. Lorem.";

function findIfDataHaveRepeatPattern ($data) {

    // First, use regex to grab all pattern at once.
    if (preg_match_all('/!\w+/u', $data, $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[0] as $crrTargetStr) {
            $targetStrCollection[] = $crrTargetStr;
        }
    }
    sort($targetStrCollection);
    // Second, sort() the array element. After sorting will makes finding duplication
    // much more easier because now we only need to check/compare
    // if every nearby element are the same or not.
    $countOfCollection = count($targetStrCollection);
    if ($countOfCollection > 1) {
        for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($targetStrCollection) ; $i++) {
            if ($i === $countOfCollection - 1) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            if ($targetStrCollection[$i] === $targetStrCollection[$i + 1]) {
                // If nearby element are the same, it means this SORTED array has duplicated pattern.
                return $targetStrCollection[$i];
            }
        }
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}


function printIfDataHaveRepeatPattern ($data) {
    $testResult = findIfDataHaveRepeatPattern($data);
    // If return value is FALSE, then nothing duplicated
    // , if return value is a string, then it is the duplicated string.

    if ($testResult) {
        echo("Duplicate on pattern " . $testResult . " in your input.");
    } else {
        echo("No duplicate pattern in your input.");
    }
}

printIfDataHaveRepeatPattern($data1);
// Will show "Duplicate on pattern !qwerty in your input.".
```

Does this solve your problem? Ask more if you need more help.